# Typing the tab character in browser text boxes

Tags: keyboard, browser

A lot of the time, when I want to format text within a web page's text box I'll hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Unfortunately, that doesn't insert the tab character but instead moves the control to the next form element (like a button or a check box).

For browsers like Firefox/IE, is there a way to get the formatting behavior of a tab, within a text box, by typing a key combination?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Tabinta](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3955) is a Firefox add-on that lets you do this.

Comment: Any solution for Chrome?

Comment: @SorinSbarnea: See my answer

Comment: It's not compatible with Firefox anymore.

Comment: This is a plugin that works in Firefox 64: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textarea-tabbing/

Comment: This plugin no longer exists (at no fault of the answer, it has been nearly a decade since the question was answered and Firefox has changed a lot).

Comment: Noted @aoeu. I flagged the answers for deletion as per https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11706/152063

Answer (score 82):

In Windows, you can push <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>. This only works with the number pad number keys. (Release <kbd>Alt</kbd> after pressing the last number key.)

Comment: Be sure you are using the NumPad keys

Comment: @Chris: When I follow those exact instructions, it doesn't insert a tab character, but acts like the tab key. Did you try this in a web browser?

Comment: @Casebash It works in this very comment window, in Chrome, in Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Only if you have Windows and a keyboard with a numpad.

Comment: ... and if you are using Chrome. FF sees it like the tab key, IE doesn't seem to do anything. Again, +1 for reminding this simple olden hack :)

Comment: @Chris, I don't think you need to release `Alt` until you've pressed *all* of the numbers.

Comment: This does not work for me in FF.

Comment: Sadly no longer working FF 36.0.1 on Windows.

Comment: While this works in many applications, it does not work on IE 11/Windows 8.

Comment: Tested and works in Chrome 59.0.3071.115, Windows 10 Pro. Best answer in my point of view, and easy to remember.  tab Thanks!

Comment: Works for me on current version of Microsoft Edge, Windows 11. I don't know why it changed behaviours, but it's back to normal now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 65):

Linux and other POSIX systems (except Mac OS):

> To input tabs in GTK+ applications (like Firefox or Chrome):
>
> 1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>
> 2. Type <kbd>9</kbd>
> 3. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Source: [Wikipedia: Unicode Input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_X11_%28Linux_and_other_Unix_variants_including_Chrome_OS%29)

Comment: It works but not useful for indenting multiple lines at once.

Comment: This worked in Chrome!

Answer (score 17):

In Safari and Firefox on Mac OS X, you can press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to insert a tab in the text field you're currently editing.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work in Chrome 50 on El Cap

Comment: Nor on Firefox 53 on Sierra.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs Still works in Safari, so it's safe to assume something changed in Firefox in the four years since I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 15):

Open Notepad or similar text editor, and start a new blank document.
Type <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
Copy your tab character to the clipboard. (On Windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will do this).

Now switch back to the textarea in your browser.
Position the cursor where you want it, and paste the tab character. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on Windows).

Voila, done!

Comment: Ciro, is it broken for regular textboxes and text input fields, or just "contenteditable" elements?  Because if it's just a problem for "contenteditable", it might not affect that many people (the OP for example)...

Comment: This was the simplest solution, unless you need to do this frequently.

Comment: No crap Sherlock. The point is to type it directly in-browser, especially in text fields, like how you would press Alt+Tab in Excel. It's a unique problem to the tab specifically in that it's a frequently used character in tabular/code formatting, but it's appropriated by browsers to jump between text fields. This so-called "solution" applies to all inaccessible characters.

Answer (score 8):

There is a Chrome plugin called [Textarea Code Formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-textarea-formatter/oglpfnoajkapekjobldcbbjhgjndbfkf).

It allows you insert tabs into text boxes in the Chrome browser. It also allows you to highlight multiple lines and insert tabs before each selected line.

However, an issue is that often you want standard tab insertion behaviour. If you do use tab to toggle between boxes, then you may to select "disabled" by default in the options.

Answer (score 4):

If it's your site:

jQuery plugin: http://teddevito.com/demos/textarea.html

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

     $("textarea").tabby();

});
```

Load jQuery and the plugin first, then you can tab and make a tab, and shift+tab to "untab" as it were.

For browser-wide support, you will have to use an extension, userscript, plugin, etc. like: 46704 for [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey).

Comment: The link is dead.  What's with all this jQuery stuff.  There's got to be a way to accept tabs using plain JavaScript.  The jQuery plugin is always nice for an already-implemented solution, but it's not really the solution.

Comment: Try this chief: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13130

Answer (score 3):

I've messed with [**AutoHotkey**](https://www.autohotkey.com/) a bit to get this ability, and the only way to put tab character into form text fields that works for me is to **paste** the tab character from clipboard.

```
;
; Paste TAB character (U+0009) from clipboard
;
CapsLock & TAB::
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
Clipboard := ""
Clipboard := A_TAB
ClipWait
Send ^v
Sleep 100
if (ClipSaved)
{
  Clipboard := ""
  Clipboard := ClipSaved
  ClipWait
  ClipSaved = ""
}
return
```

This occasionally comes in handy even outside browsers.

Comment: This worked for me.  I changed `CapsLock & Tab::` to  `^TAB::` so that CTRL+TAB will paste the tab character (instead of switching browser tabs). I am a big fan of AutoHotkey.

Answer (score 1):

The big advantage of [Tabinta](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3955) in **Firefox** is that you can map the tab character to another hotkey, since you really don't want to lose the tab key default behavior in the browser.

With **Internet Explorer** you have no solution in the way of browser extensions that I am aware of. Here the only way is to keep the tab character in the clipboard by having previously copied it from some other program like notepad.

javascript solutions require the name of the textbox where they will act on, so this is far from ideal or practical. While alt keycode combinations under both browsers still execute the normal tab character keypress event so they don't work either.

Answer (score 0):

To type the tab key in a text box, you can use a script like this (text box which accepts tab keys is named `txtLongText`):

> #### [VB.NET]
>
> ```
> txtLongText.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", _
> "if(event.which || event.keyCode){if ((event.which == 9)" & _ 
> "|| (event.keyCode == 9)) {document.getElementById('" & _ 
> txtLongText.ClientID + "').selection = " & _
> document.selection.createRange();" & _ 
> txtLongText.ClientID & ".selection.text = " & _
> " String.fromCharCode(9);return false;}} else {return true}; ")
> ```
>
> #### [C#]
>
> ```
> txtLongText.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", 
> "if(event.which || event.keyCode){if ((event.which == 9)" +
> "|| (event.keyCode == 9)) {document.getElementById('"+
> txtLongText.ClientID + "').selection = document.selection.createRange();" + 
> txtLongText.ClientID + ".selection.text = String.fromCharCode(9);return false;}} else {return true}; ");
> ```

Or better, to avoid hard coding, you can put this code in a function named `EnableTabType`. The function has only one parameter, which specifies what is `TextBox` control where you need to enable typing of Tab characters.

> #### [VB.NET]
>
> ```
> Public Sub EnableTabType(tb As TextBox)
>     tb.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", _
>     "if(event.which || event.keyCode){if((event.which == 9)" & _ 
>     "|| (event.keyCode == 9)) {document.getElementById('" & _ 
>     tb.ClientID & "').selection=document.selection.createRange();" & _
>     tb.ClientID & ".selection.text = " & _
>     " String.fromCharCode(9);return false;}}else{return true};")
> End Sub
> ```
>
> #### [C#]
>
> ```
> public void EnableTabType(TextBox tb)
> { 
>     tb.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", 
>     "if(event.which || event.keyCode){if ((event.which == 9)" +
>     "|| (event.keyCode == 9)) {document.getElementById('"+
>     tb.ClientID + "').selection = document.selection.createRange();" +
>     tb.ClientID + ".selection.text = String.fromCharCode(9);return false;}} else {return true}; ");
> }
> ```

Source: http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Access-Tab-Key.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Tab Grabber](http://www.sitekickr.com/blog/tab-grabber-chrome-extension/) is kinda like Tabinta, only for Chrome (allows TABs in textarea fields).

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuerry's tabby! Supports select row and press tab odr SHIFT TAB

http://www.herby.sk/trapped/bower_components/jquery-tabby/textarea.mirror.html

Answer (score 0):

or using ahk to insert 4*space in editor:

```
^Right::
tabspace:="    "
send,%tabspace%    
return
```

you can see code details explaintation in [ahk code](http://instrum.xyz/2017/02/05/autohotkeyahk-replace-tab-in-web-page/)