# Inserting a tab character in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Typing the tab character in browser text boxes](https://superuser.com/questions/67934/typing-the-tab-character-in-browser-text-boxes)

Firefox makes it hard to insert a tab. Whenever I hit <kbd>tab</kbd> it changes the focus. Currently, the only workaround I know of is to put a tab in the clipboard and paste instead. Anyone have a better solution?

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work on all browsers.

Comment: @Eight: I know, its just that I wanted to know if someone had a better solution than cut and paste

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/67934/typing-the-tab-character-in-browser-text-boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously mentioned, by default <kbd>Tab</kbd> will change focus to another field in most browsers. This allows people to navigate without a mouse. If you want to actually insert a tab character into textareas, you can use the [**Tabinta add-on**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3955) (Tabinta = Tab in textarea). Tabinta also lets you use an alternate character to insert a tab, if you want to keep the default tab functionality set for the tab key.

Comment: This add-on isn't compatible with Firefox anymore.

Comment: The URL no longer works either (at no fault of the answer, it has been nearly a decade since this question was answered and Firefox has changed a lot).

Answer (score 3):

You can push ALT + 09

Comment: Why on EARTH was this downvoted? It's PERFECT!

Comment: It seems not to work in Firefox. It works perfectly in the notepad but in Firefox nothing happens.

Comment: I downvoted this because it's not at all clear what pushing "ALT + 09" means.