# Text indentation via Tab-key in the Windows Google Chrome browser without using extensions or a Numpad?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser

When trying to indent a block of text in an input textfield, for instance to emphasize Markdown code-blocks, the Tab key is already bound to a different action (switching to the next input element).

What is a straightforward way to overcome this issue without using extensions?

I found these two threads, but unfortunately don't have a Numpad, and the answers presume installed extensions or applications:

[How to use Tab key to indent within a textfield (instead of jumping to next element)?](https://superuser.com/questions/522627/how-to-use-tab-key-to-indent-within-a-textfield-instead-of-jumping-to-next-elem)

[Typing the tab character in browser text boxes](https://superuser.com/questions/67934/typing-the-tab-character-in-browser-text-boxes)

Without having a Numpad, one can use the following key-combination on Linux POSIX Systems:

```
Control+Shift+U9
```

I am looking for something similar on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/),
the following one-line script can send
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>
whenever <kbd>F12</kbd> is pressed:

```
F12:: Send {LAlt DOWN}{Numpad0}{Numpad9}{LAlt UP}
```

I have tested this on Chrome for a `textarea` tag with NumLock on and off,
and it worked for both cases.
It might not work when the webpage includes JavaScript that handles entered keys.

Comment: Flagged by the bounty poster: "I can't comment because after publishing bounty I went to down under 50 but please tell Harry that AHk isn't the solution for me and I published this question which is more specific: http://superuser.com/questions/1452001"