# Adding tabulation characters to MediaWiki

Tags: linux, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, mediawiki

If one wants to [nest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesting_(computing)) any HTML tag inside another HTML tag in MediaWiki, **space-indentation** isn't useful for that because it causes the nested tags to be wrapped in a `<pre>` tag in execution.
A possible solution to this problem is using **tabulation-indentation** instead.

Sadly, hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> when in MediaWiki edit page doesn't add tabulation character.
What will be a fast way to add tabulation-characters to a MediaWiki edit page?

<sub>1. Creating an empty tab character and copying it and pasting it each time anew isn't a good solution IMHO.</sub>
<sub>2. [In this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/640752/text-indentation-via-tab-key-in-the-windows-google-chrome-browser-without-using/1451916#1451916) HarryMC suggests an AHk approach, but this is not helpful to Linux users.</sub>

Comment: Question edited to clarify.

Comment: Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/123638/preventing-mediawiki-from-wrapping-space-indented-content-in-pre-html-tags